Help with kerning
I'm kerning this word for logo, and I'm unsure about the kerning, especially the gap between "l" and "f". How would you adjust the kerning, if needed?

Are there general rules for how to kern hooked letters, such as "f" and "t"? Most online resources I found address only kerning straight and rounded letters.

Hi. I would be inclined to say that if the kerning looks good to you, then it's probably good enough for anybody. I think what you have done is totally fine. Kerning is generally done optically, according to your own judgement. The only "rule" is that the spacing should look even. There's an online game called Kerntype where you can practice kerning. I have no affiliation with the site. There are also tutorials on youtube. I'm hesitant to answer this question however as kerning is somewhat subjective. There's no absolute right or wrong.

Just in case you happen to want another opinion without any proofs based on any theories here's one:

Letters l and f are detached in Photoshop from your original image and moved rightwards. How much and why? Just as much as you see. The grey one is your original. The reason: It looked subjectively wrong.
To stay in truth the e was moved at first, but it was moved back after 2 seconds, because it started to look loose.

Haha, ok, thanks. I'll try playing around with moving the "l" and "f" a little.
